# How to configure an App to run at every bootup of mobile?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

In `Titanium Appcelerator` how can I configure my `App` to start running as soon as the mobile boots ? any Ideas ?
 Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To listen for system boot event you should register a `BroadcastReceiver` listening for the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` action. In its `onReceive()` method you can start any other application components like `Services` or `Activities`. Hope this helps.